# How I get the list of all products purchased in my app by Google Play Developer API

Tags: google-play-developer-api

I want the list of all products purchased in my app. But in the Google Play Developer API documentation, I am only finding a GET request for individual products. Is there a GET request to list all products that have already been purchased?

(I am building an individual application to view, more easily and in an automated way, the recipes of my apps)

Documentation that I'm looking at: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products/get

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no LIST API for in app products or subscription purchase as from Publisher API docs now.

The Publisher API is only for querying the product or subscription purchase by purchase token, and have no link to the user google account. That may be the reason that a LIST API is not available.

I recommend you to store your purchase in a relational table with a userID linked to your app login ID, so you can make the LIST API from your own server.

To update the purchase and products, use the Publisher API and Real-time notifications.

Answer (score 0):

> When querying for product details, pass an instance of
> QueryProductDetailsParams that specifies a list of product ID strings
> created in Google Play Console along with a ProductType. The
> ProductType can be either ProductType.INAPP for one-time products or
> ProductType.SUBS for subscriptions.

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate

here's how:

```
    private fun queryPurchases() {
    val product1 =
        QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
            .setProductId("sku_1")
            .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.INAPP)
            .build()
    val product2 =
        QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
            .setProductId("sku_2")
            .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.INAPP)
            .build()
    val queryProductDetailsParams =
        QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
            .setProductList(
                ImmutableList.of(product1, product2)
            )
            .build()

    billingClient.queryProductDetailsAsync(queryProductDetailsParams) { billingResult, productDetailsList ->
        // check billingResult
        // process returned productDetailsList
    }

}
```